# Adjusted R-squared is too high (=1) in Linear Model

Tags: r, linear-regression

I built a Linear model which has an adjusted r-squared value of 1. I understand that this is a near perfect number. Upon further investigation, I found that one of the 96 independent variables in the dataset is highly correlated with the dependent variable. This is also a variable which I would like to keep (and not drop). Are there any additional steps that I should undertake to handle this?

Sample df reproducing the situation above:

```
df1 <- data.frame("y" =   c(0.0166 , -0.2380 , -0.3192 , -0.2774 ,  9.3148 , 0.3142) , 
          "x1" =  c(0.0103 , -0.2347 ,  -0.3182 , -0.2793 ,  9.4638  , 0.3297) , 
          "x2" = c( -0.1838 , -0.2458 , -0.2581 ,-0.2533 , 6.7566 ,-0.0835) , 
          "x3" = c(0.3426 ,-0.0543 ,-0.4512 ,-0.0543, 10.4637 , 0.3426) ,
          "x4" = c(-0.161 , -0.270 ,-0.318, -0.280 , 8.279 , 0.169))
df1
df1_lm <- lm(y~. , data = df1)
summary(df1_lm)
```

Comment: Question: is your „good“ x feature a linear combination of y?

Comment: Why would you like to keep the variable, and why do you think the r2 value's too high?

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly disagree with Viktor an adjusted r² of 1 is not "luck to have a good model" it is a clear indicator of data leakage and a model that will absolutely overfit on new data!

To mediate this you need to understand your data and domain better (which means we need more infos to help).

But generally try to answer the following questions:

1. In any case I have not measured Y would I also be unable to measure X (the good variable)?
2. Is X a derivative value of Y? E.g. if you try to predict height in meters it does not make sense to include height in cm, you'd simply calculate it.
3. What is my use case? Do you want to explain relations / impact, do you want to predict something on new unseen data, etc.? Depending on the use case you have to deal with it in different ways.

It does not make sense however to keep this variable in your model because it invalidates the need for the model in the first place.

Either you could go ahead simply calculating Y from X and ignore all other variables (in case it is a simply unit conversion or a deterministic classifier like age > 18y --> adult) or you have to remove X to actually learn something about all the other variables (in case you want to explore impact / relation of other variables).

Also keep in mind that unless the linear regression of Y and the single good X is also r² = 1 you might have to remove or cluster two variables!

Answer (score -1):

You are lucky to have a good model, no need to handle this if there is no information leakage from y to your x1 variable.

Checking the data you provided you may want to eliminate variables that are not significant though.

Comment: Thanks Viktor . Btw , what is 'information leakage' that you are referring to ? and how can i check for it ?

Comment: I meant if there was some error  during data collection or variable selection and somehow your y variable effected your x variable. I.e. you want to predict who will win the lottery (y) and you use the bank account balance (x1) to predict. If x1 was collected after the payment of the prize you will have probably a very good model even though in practice it will be useless. If I see such an almost deterministic model I always get suspicious and check this option. It shall depend on your domain but  it can be normal too to have a good value.